# Laravel routing

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm new to laravel and I'm having trouble with routing.

What I'm trying to do is use my routes like so

Domain/{controller}/{action }

So that I can go to the home's test page

Home/test

The documentation doesn't really make sense to me so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Currently I'm hardcoding my routes for every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could start with:

```
Route::get('Domain/{controller}/{action?}', function ($controller, $action = 'index') {

    $class = $controller.'Controller';
    $controller = new $class()

    return $controller - > {
        $action
    }();

}) -> where(array('controller' = > '[a-z]+', 'action' = > '[a-z]+'))
```

And you can change Route::get with Route::any to catch it all

Other simple tested example (should be working:)

Route::any('{controller}/{action?}', function($controller, $action = 'index')
{

```
$class = $controller . 'Controller';
$controller = new $class();
return $controller->{$action}();
```

});

Comment: change Route::get with Route::any to catch it all ;)

Comment: This is what I wanted but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: 1) What's the name of the controller? Does it Ends with 'Controller', if not you can remove it from the code. 2) return $controller->{$action}(); is one line. 3) What's the error ^^?

Comment: It's "HomeController" with an action of "index" so I would hope to use it like domain.com/home/index

Comment: Did you remove 'Domain/' from the Route::get?

Comment: Yes this is my result Route::get('/{controller}/{action?}', function ($controller, $action = 'index') {

    $class = $controller.'Controller';
    $controller = new $class()

    return $controller - > {
        $action
    }();

}) -> where(array('controller' = > '[a-z]+', 'action' = > '[a-z]+'));

Comment: Is the uppercased 'Home' from 'HomeController' here the issue, while using home with lowercase in the url?

Comment: Yeah i've tried with both but i think it may be something wrong with my actions, ill update if i find a fix. Thank you.!

Comment: I tried your code, but its giving error Class not found for `$controller = new $class()`. I wrote your code in routes.php using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1):

```
Basic GET Route

Route::get('controller/method', function()
{
 //
});

Basic POST Route

Route::post('controller/method', function()
{

});

Named Route:

Route::get('controller/action', array('uses' =>'Controller@method'));
```

Suppose it is your form action:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'register.store')) }}
```

then you can write the code for routing as:

```
Route::get('register', array(
  'uses' => 'RegisterController@index',
  'as' => 'register.index'
));
Route::post('register', array(
  'uses' => 'RegisterController@store',
  'as' => 'register.store'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much knowledge on Laravel framework. But overall this should work:

```
Route::get('Domain/{controller}/{action}', function($controller, $action)
{
    //
})
->where(array('controller' => '[a-z]+', 'action' => '[a-z]+'))
```

Comment: What do I return in this function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the routing like this:

```
Route::get('/orders/nieuw', 'OrdersController@nieuw');
Route::post('/orders/nieuw', 'OrdersController@save_nieuw');
Route::get('/orders/edit/{orderId}', 'OrdersController@edit');
Route::post('/orders/edit/{orderId}', 'OrdersController@save_edit');
Route::get('/orders/show/{idPartij}', 'OrdersController@show');
Route::get('/orders/show_row/{idPartij}/{row_id}', 'OrdersController@show_row');
Route::get('/orders/{active?}', 'OrdersController@index');
```

Simplified version:

`Route::get` is simply saying: When we receive an get route, which meets the conditions, do something.

The condition `('/orders/nieuw'` is in an URL translated to `http://www.domain.com/orders/nieuw`

If that conditions is met, where going to use the `OrdersController` and execute the function `nieuw` ( which is an `public function` inside the `OrdersController class`)

The same works for `post` requests.

Params can you pass with `{param}`. And if you have an not necessary param you can use `{param?}`

If you need more info, let me know

**EDIT 1**
if you read [this](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers), then you should say that the following is the clossest as it can get:

```
Route::get('home/test');
Route::get('home/test2');
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
```

That way, you only have to declare the controller 1 time, and the non standard links...

Comment: That's sort of what I have happening at the moment. I just want a way to not have to specify a route to every single action.