# Laravel 5.2 routing like cakephp

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I am coming form cakephp, so routing is creating a bit of difficulty for me.

I have tried the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529035/laravel-routing/) but getting error in that.
I also tried for `Route::controller();` and `Route::resource();` but not getting the the result i want.

I simply want the rounting to be

```
http://example.com/controller/action/param1/param2/param3
```

also, if i can get answer for the backend management like

```
http://example.com/backend/controller/action/param1/param2/param3
```

Comment: I think it is not in build in laravel. But if you have created the resource route then you have all routes already created by laravel for you.  Because when you are creating the route or resource controller as `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');` then laravel creates the routes as `photos/create,photos/edit/id,photos/update/id,photos/save,photos/show/id,photos/destroy/id` with appropriate POST , GET method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2 the use of `Route::controller('Controller')` has been deprecated due to annoying race conditions.

To get your desired result. Let's say you have a controller `App\Http\Controllers\MyController`.

In your `routes.php` file you would have the following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(Router $router) {

    // Note the question marks after the parameters
    // this makes them optional.
    $router->get('uri/{action?}/{param1?}/{param2?}', [
        'uses' => 'MyController@getIndex'
    ]);
});
```

You would now have a controller method `getIndex`

```
// As the parameters were optional, make sure to give them
// default values.
public function getIndex($action = null, $param1 = null, $param2 = null)
{
    // Your route logic
}
```

Comment: what if i have more than one controller, do i have to write seperate route for each one ?

Comment: To avoid the race conditions that using `Route::controller` introduces, the answer is yes.

Comment: Unless your controllers are resource controllers in which case a simple `Route::resource(App\Http\Controllers\ResourceController::class);` will do.

Comment: May i have i conversation [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104527/room-for-aipd-tech-and-david-barker)

Answer (score 1):

im coming from cakephp too, and i write this route for emulate cakephp routing.

```
    Route::any('{anyRoute}', function($anyRoute){
         $call = "";
         $parts = explode("/", $anyRoute);
         $size = sizeof($parts);

         if($size > 0){
             $controller = ucfirst(strtolower(trim($parts[0])));
             $action = trim(array_get($parts, 1));
             $params = [];

             if(empty($controller)){
                 return view("welcome");
             }
             else{
                 if(empty($action)){
                     $action = "index";
                 }
             }

             if($size > 2){
                 unset($parts[0], $parts[1]);
                 $params = array_merge($params, $parts);
             }

             $object = app('App\\Http\\Controllers\\'.$controller.'Controller');
             call_user_func_array([$object, $action], $params);
         }

    })->where('anyRoute', '(.*)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get params i thinks this way maybe helps you:

i assume you want to get params

```
//App/routes.php

Route::get( '/controller/action/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}' , 'ActionController@getParams' );



//App/Http/Controllers/ActionController.php

public function getParams($param1, $param2, $param3 )
    {
        return $param1.$param2.$param3;
    }
```

for second part it's same.

for more information: [laravel controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources)

Comment: what if i have more than one controller, do i have to write seperate route for each one ?

Comment: @AIPDTECH no you don't, you can use ExistController@getParams and after that create public function with name getParams.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn’t have implicit routing like CakePHP (like you, I moved from CakePHP to Laravel). You’re better off defining resource routes, i.e.

```
$router->resources([
    'users' => 'UserController',
    'articles' => 'ArticleController',
    'events' => 'EventController',
    // And so on...
]);
```

This has the benefit of people being able to see what routes your application responds to by looking over your **app/Http/routes.php** file, rather than having to delve into your controller classes and seeing what actions you’ve defined in them.